# Replication with Veeam causes timeouts on large VM's

Tags: vmware-esx, replication, snapshot, veeam

I have been trying to replicate two of my larger VM's one being Exchange 2003 and once the snapshot begins to commit the server begins to time out. I have updates my ESX hosts from 4.0.0 to 4.1 and now it is worse. My snapshots are taking even longer to commit. Anyone know how to make the snapshots commit without causing the VM to have network latency?

Answer (score 0):

That was a VMware issue in 3.5/4.x ESX(i) versions. They now have it fixed, just use 5.x modern versions of ESXi. [A reference to old KB about that](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004932)